# A proper way to create a chrooted SSH on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, sftp, chroot

There are a lot of tutorials of how to create a chrooted SFTP, but I would like to use SSH, because it is much faster to simply `wget`, `unzip`, `mysql` and `mysqldump` than tossing around the FTP and phpMyAdmin. The method should be also clean (without the manual `ldd` magic) and extensible, so I can add and upgrade packages easily.

Comment: If your question would be closed as off-topic, I suggest to try it again on http://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 3):

Luckily, I was able to come up with a way to do that.

**Step 1: Add a group for chrooted users**

```
groupadd chrootusers
```

**Step 2: Configure SSH**

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Replace

```
Subsystem     sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

With

```
Subsystem     sftp    internal-sftp
```

Paste at the End

```
Match Group chrootusers
  ChrootDirectory /home/%u
```

Run

```
systemctl restart sshd
systemctl status sshd
```

**Step 3: Add a user**

Change `peter` to your desired user name.

```
export NEW_USER_NAME=peter

useradd ${NEW_USER_NAME}
usermod -G chrootusers -d / ${NEW_USER_NAME}
passwd ${NEW_USER_NAME}
```

**Step 4: Install packages and create the necessary directory structure**

```
yum --installroot=/home/${NEW_USER_NAME} --releasever=7 --nogpg --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=base install centos-release openssh-clients wget vi nano zip unzip tar mariadb findutils iputils bind-utils rsync
```

**Step 5: Mount `proc` and `dev`**

```
echo "none /home/${NEW_USER_NAME}/proc proc defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
echo "/dev /home/${NEW_USER_NAME}/dev none bind 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

Run

```
mount -a
```

**Step 6: Configure the DNS servers**

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /home/${NEW_USER_NAME}/etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /home/${NEW_USER_NAME}/etc/resolv.conf
```

**That's all.**

Keep in mind that `$NEW_USER_NAME` is bound to the current session!

Start from Step 3 when adding another user.

To install more packages later use the same command as in Step 4.

---

When logging in using SSH you will get messages like `cannot find name for user ID x`. They are safe to ignore, but if you'd like to get rid of them, you will need to duplicate the user in chroot:

```
export NEW_USER_ID=$(id -u ${NEW_USER_NAME})
export NEW_USER_GROUP_ID=$(id -g ${NEW_USER_NAME})

chroot /home/${NEW_USER_NAME} /bin/bash -c 'useradd -u ${NEW_USER_ID} ${NEW_USER_NAME}'
chroot /home/${NEW_USER_NAME} /bin/bash -c 'groupadd -g ${NEW_USER_GROUP_ID} chrootusers'
```

Comment: What would the bare minimum package list be, if I only needed to have capability of SFTP to drop or retrieve files?

Comment: I found a way to do this without providing all of these extra packages for the chrooted user:  http://serverfault.com/a/797967/98791