# Lock Home Folder down for specific users (CENT OS)

Tags: centos, useradd

I am running multiple users on my VPS with CentOS 7 64 bit. And, I want to be able to lock down their home directory. I want them to be able to access all sub folders in that home directory but not be able to go up[ via SSH or SFTP.

thanks for your help.

Comment: chroot is probably what you want

Comment: @Systemsninja how can I do that (in a command)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/699346/a-proper-way-to-create-a-chrooted-ssh-on-centos-7